# Transition is not working for height:0px

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I am trying to reveal a div on click of a button present at the bottom of page , so i have given a smooth  transition for that . the problem is when i click the button it reveals a div with transition but while un-revealing it its shuts down all the way without any transition.
 here is snippet

```
<div class="jump reveal">  <!-- media -->
   <!-- Thumbnail images -->
   <div class="row" id="gallry">   <!-- imagecontainer -->
    <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="random.png" style="max-width:100%" 
      alt="Page 1">
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
  <a class="button page expand " id="caption"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

the css :

```
.jump{
    display: none;
    background-color:#2f2f2f;
    transition: 2s all linear;
    }
   @-webkit-keyframes slideup{
    0%{bottom: -200px}
    100%{bottom: 0px}
   }
  .page{
      position:fixed;
      bottom: 0px;
     left: 75%;
     width: 80px;
     height: 25px;``
     font-size: 1rem;
     color: white;
     padding-top: 4px;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: black;
     border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
     z-index: 2;
     transition: 0.2s all ease;
     -webkit-transition:0.2s all ease;
     -o-transition:0.2s all ease;
   }
   .expand{
     bottom: 250px;
     position: fixed;
     transition: 0.2s all ease;
     -o-transition:0.2s all ease;
     -webkit-transition:0.2s all ease;
     z-index: 2;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
  .reveal{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
   float: left;
   background-color: black;
   overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-animation:slideup 0.2s ease;
  animation: slideup 0.2s ease;
  -o-animation:slideup 0.2s ease;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 3;
 }
```

jquery:

```
  $(".page").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
    $(".jump").toggleClass("reveal");
 }
```

Comment: Because you forget close perantis ! [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwvw3ncf/)

Comment: tq @pedram but that isnt resolving my query , as in the playground ,you see the abrupt move of button to the bottom when  u unreveal it .

Comment: i am trying to achive asmooth transition even while hiding the div..

Comment: and @Pedram where exactly do you mean by  that "parentis" ?

Comment: `$(".page").click(function() {` you open `parentis` here, before `function` but not closed at end.

Comment: Your html is not complete. Where is the page class div?

Comment: attribute tag itself acts a div, as i considered button class and modified its css using PAGE value. @NanditaAroraSharma

Comment: @Pedram - oops thats my posting issue sry i have actually closed it ! so that donot consider that as an error

Comment: Try this [codepen](https://codepen.io/mbxtr/pen/pCfcy). This might help you

Comment: @mudit  i actualy want the button transition not the inner div

Answer (score 0):

When you used       `-webkit-animation:slideup 0.2s ease;`
 `animation: slideup 0.2s ease;`
  `-o-animation:slideup 0.2s ease;` in the `main <div>` If in the div below re-use , It affects twice = `-webkit-animation:slideup 0.4s ease;` ....

So remove them from `.page`

css :

```
.jump {
  display: none;
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  transition: 2s all linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideup {
  0% {
    bottom: -200px
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0px
  }
}

.page {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 75%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  z-index: 2;

}

.expand {
  bottom: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  transition: 0.2s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.2s all ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s all ease;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.reveal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: slideup 0.2s ease;
  animation: slideup 0.2s ease;
  -o-animation: slideup 0.2s ease;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/sourcechanger/8tzt9929/)